# Is there an efficient way to get all values of a certain type from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, types

Suppose that I have an array in no particular order, and I want to get all values of a given type from that array (for this example, let's use strings).

```js
oldArray = [1, "2", {3: 4}, 5, "6", /7/];
/* ... */
newArray = ["2", "6"];
```

Logically, I would do something like this:

```js
newArray = [];
oldArray.forEach((element) => {
  if (typeof element === "string") {
    newArray.push(element);
  }
});
```

(Though it isn't as elegant as the Python one-liner `[value for value in oldArray if type(value) == str]`, it still suffices for me.)

---

My question is: **Is there a more efficient way to do this, or is this an optimal solution?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```js
const oldArray = [1, "2", {3: 4}, 5, "6", /7/];

const newArray = oldArray.filter(e => typeof e === 'string');

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `array.filter()`:

```
newArray = oldArray.filter(e => typeof e == "string")
```

Comment: Yeah, this is absolutely the way to go. Marking this one as accepted because it predates the other answer.

Comment: @wibbuffey ... *code review* mode ... but the other answer got provided as executable snippet which takes more time to write. And ... it uses *strict equal* for comparison. Also `newArray` with `const` versus globally initialized. (btw ... Nobody should feel hurt or insulted. This comment was merely for emphasizing how puzzled I'm about the criteria of an accepted answer.)

Comment: @PeterSeliger True... I'm not really sure which to accept. I've already committed to accepting this one, so I probably will. Sorry!! (EDIT: Second-guessing myself...)

Comment: @PeterSeliger There's no need to use strict equality here. `typeof` *always* returns a string.

Comment: @Barmar ... I know. I on purpose wanted to sound like an unhumorous programmer's guide and strict linting advocate.